# Como remover a hashtag (#) da URL?

Tags: angularjs

Por padrão o AngularJs formata a URL da seguinte maneira:

`http://dominio.com.br/#/login`

Como faço para deixá-la da seguinte maneira?

`http://dominio.com.br/login`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

São dois passos bem simples:

- Habilitar o HTML5 no `$locationProvider`
- Configurar o caminho base da aplicação

### Habilitar HTML5

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : homeController
      })
      .when('/sobre', {
        templateUrl : 'sobre.html',
        controller : sobreController
      });

      // habilitar o uso da API HTML5 History
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

### Definir url base no Index da aplicação

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

Fonte: [URLs bonitas em AngularJS: Removendo o # (Em Inglês)](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)