# Como tirar a '#' da URL AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

A URL da minha aplicação está assim 'http://localhost/ssga/#/login'. Estou tentando tirar a '#' da URL, já tentei de várias formas mas não estou conseguindo. Tenho o seguinte código.

config.js:

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider, IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider) {

// Configure Idle settings
IdleProvider.idle(5); // in seconds
IdleProvider.timeout(120); // in seconds

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
// $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

$ocLazyLoadProvider.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    // Set to true if you want to see what and when is dynamically loaded
    debug: false
}]);
```

index.html:

```
<head>
   ...
   <base href="/">
</head>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como remover a hashtag (#) da URL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/133743/como-remover-a-hashtag-da-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não é possível pois o caractere "#" faz parte da mecânica de roteamento do Angular.

Para "retirar" esse caractere, você terá que levar o roteamento para o lado do servidor, seja utilizando um framework (recomendado) ou algo mais "artesanal" com a criação de pastas no servidor.